# having problems using ajax to call a php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

on clientside(js) im using this script

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "editold.php",
    data: "call=generateCode",
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Succesful getting php file");
    },
    error: function (response) {
         alert("Error getting php file");
    }
});
```

on serverside(php) im using this code:

```
<?php 



if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET") {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . 'alert(" ' . 'hey' . '");' . '</script>'; 
$function = $_GET['call'];

    if(function_exists($function)) {        
        call_user_func($function);
    } 
    else {
        echo 'Function Not Exists!!';
    }
}

function generateCode() {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . 'alert(" ' . 'hey' . '");' . '</script>'; 
}
?>
```

Although I do get an alert saying my success function alert meaning the file
was loaded succesfully I dont seem to be getting the final generatecode function to work.(I dont get a second alert.)

i've tried lots of things but nothing seems to work.

What do i do?..

Comment: I think your data sent from the client should be an object, and not `"call=generateCode"`.  After further thought, it doesn't need to be an object, but I still question your implementation.

Comment: You don't actually do anything with the response, so your code is behaving as it should.  The response is not evaluated, and it isn't executed, so you'd never see a second alert, or even a third.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "editold.php",
    data: {call: "generateCode"}, // <-- This one is changed into an object
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Succesful getting php file");
        $('body').append(response); // <-- Append the ajax response to the page body
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("Error getting php file");
    }
});
```

If not, try doing `var_dump($_GET);` in your PHP file.

Comment: Nothing is ever done with the response, so how would this change what's happening?

Comment: It should be '"call"' with quotes, not 'call'!

Comment: @Daedalus Thank you! I've added a little append function to the success callback.

Comment: @siluaty Quotes are needed in JSON, not JS.

Comment: And the data not being in object form [is not the problem](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  It's always good to read the documentation before making a claim like that.

Comment: @Shomz You have solved my primary problem Thanks alot. I would love it if you could look at my new comment and help me with a new little problem that came up next..

Comment: For that new error, try opening the php file directly from your browser, make sure you enable error_reporting and see what errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

1-At server side send the response without script tag.

2-At client side use eval() function to execute your code.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET") {
echo 'alert(" ' . 'hey' . '");';
$function = $_GET['call'];

if(function_exists($function)) {        
    call_user_func($function);
} 
else {
    echo 'Function Not Exists!!';
}
}

function generateCode() {
//your code 
}


jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "editold.php",
    data: "call=generateCode",
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Succesful getting php file");

        eval(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("Error getting php file");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot Shomz it solved my primary problem. but now I have a new little problem :( if you could please help me with this one to.. Now when i change the alert into the code I actually wanted to execute :     $db = ConnectToSQLAndGetDBConnSTRVar();
    $NewQuery = "UPDATE subtopics SET SubTopic_Name='asfasfa' WHERE SubTopic_ID='spirituality'";
    $db->query($NewQuery); it suddenly wont load the php file it gives me the alert of the error function "Error getting php file"